# Совет по решению задачи на реакте

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть массив объектов, который я вывожу map'ом в jsx. Так же при нажатии на кнопку enter на элементе массива, я вызываю функцию с аргументом id объекта. Мне нужно что бы при нажатии на arrowKeys я переключал активный класс на каждом элементе массива, и при нажатии на enter, что бы вызывалась функция на том элементе на котором сейчас стоит активный класс или например дата атрибут. То есть по сути, мне нужно как то выбирать каждый item массива стрелками. Как лучше это решить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[там песочница](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?target=99&jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoUSWRYmAEQHkBZObXAo9GAWgBNcZcgHphcHgBoeIsZOloIAOwDO8AMJIANpoBctbgDoAYmoA8yQ2tyRFSRTAAKOMMtP5lYFIvwA%20H3ABeOAAKAG84NAALYE0%20IkUJOANksGdlOABfAEpA-2DyOEK4Uw8vOFDkg1SIFwyfUKiYuLsM02FSxR9yLPIFFXgECAB3PQsMYzMxmAMrcCU7RzS3PmAAN19-ILCI6Nj4xMrql0ycgLyCotMV1fLDtLqG3ebFVuFrrp7RcSlyOwBXPAAaQAogBNADK5QuhQAglAcEMAKpgQIEOEI5H4CTQuDo4b0YaKVH4PFDAlDbzYoq4%20HDAAySEw8CCJNpQwZTKxONJCGAAHNIsy0WzeQKYFzqcD7EgoKiAERSmAyuXYjIyb7yJSqODMFAwKDAAAeozoE3MptmNgWThqrnw118cAAZOU4CA9QbjXAvABPADaAF1A5lNiFwu79UaTrkodS%20tq0FpNOCYD7NEgTZZweCbWAZTBgEh0kFQjjqSsPJoUD69PhgIpNPWkDwAEaaCBoADWWLgSsNMBhjb5ilrielUHwOLVcaTKbTSAMjdsAAkkPzBajE9o5%20mDENgHwYJFN7PU7vImuxcSAMwABjAhsn1K%20chx8fgfs7SB9iWUSBggLfgGqJTAYfx-imepIME%20Bfj6%20A9HGWofoaP5wH%20MAABqgsBQSgeBSCQUq2xereiQ1nAt4nDi6bwOEhrkZkqKoW%20yFwEQGGosEpz%20OEJGMRkzE%20jk05FO%20cCGrqhqohGnp%20reAaLnYfJHuIcAAIwUEh-RwD6UkyR6RpKYoKnHjwGlaUUL4-Np2qRF4fDpoBPpOEWxYhEgqwLJm4zOS2EAoFAfDAl59g8bG1JiWx4RwUxQSeQsZZWbINmRYUGHOcEcGIWlcDWdIuURGxfCoqWhXUn6IIQgYpLIgGejcTGPA8D%20SVpZVYLgjVbLkoo9UhOFADUg2teVRQddVpIcjA-WNWc4g8AxbWRRNXU8uuM0NUNg1LWNhSrQYioyrN4XhBkVK5aJaX5ct4nAMoAAqUB-EgqIAI4xvqL2BAEQRvZZaV3cojC2FxDG6eF6k-UEslGn6PpBoaAa3WxUSlctFVVWtbJ1VtMbw3A-hkYpCVQD6wT3U9L1ZBdY0HaSvUnfjPrFLpUkSCTXlkxTj3PUgNMY%20NWPdQi01M-NfrSUTHMGKT5OU3zAt7XA9Miht4v%20JLrOSSgDGczK8u89TtPlQdR1QBrKtfUg%20vcwrxvLVdkU3YVQOMICqKxfWOzOi6XtEnwy3AJgIQAIT3e7ORlXt8YQLuQyBYoMH%20zsPYp1EOVjbH8eJ8n35wN7fBp-nheZ%20VRAwH8UCKADkVO9SQy7K9wRRJ%20QHcVHguFHwbcI9xXcFyHPMg9B4PCZ3yvUhh2H8bp1GT0ULZcJ2teFfXRTr4UwdhxHtjBGPWQ5Bx-794VLsbzi5%20FC%20cBSGwHbgTR-5wNcPnTMwfwwCgbZIMgmCMC2AAVkgDAphlwPWYHSegaxgTphAAsUMig-jaEvmIa4IFTQET-mAiBUCYFwIQafZKcBaIq0wL%20f8RhcL6HGARIi0FMAoE0H%20MuXx8J-mBJgTAICYDBDmrxVBkVxKNm1EEP0%20A0CNi7D2fA7YUBFwDLXL4tksAP3cvwiK18xCFW3sEa4Bg0BV3iDACexDlb6MMfCBYBhMBqKIVo8qTtlEX2fNoooIjpi2KgMCdAkRgiqFlPNAQhj4H2AMP5PgPoDDyOCqFGAdJ7pKlsFAfx%20pEi2MMcoQ%20gjqS6NDpgUxDjXZajjgudsfISLszZrreeZjcoYSMMEa2rC3GFCca09i-4q5Eg0dHIpuUPE2OgD4qIqTAn%20GCQCaxESolEBABALyIUFgJNUHYGUYz0lqOya4uugjsiCMkGpDJj8VFwDeh9Esy0WzoE7HyHAfxFB8CsO2KAtYvAFjei9RuwAlQSlyu6KAfJ6zTTeZ-CAfy0oAqBYoUUgpQUwHBSbBuB4jy1nUgAVnvI%20E2gkUDpFAmobMuZ8yFmUAc1KhQK7dJCMtK4axezfwAJKPKQIaAIoRbyCSUM5Xq7L7KPKct%20VyyhlCCVUPOdl5zN6RSIJgdl1xpVdGVqYMA9Q4KvFVQPFV9RDSCVCD6DVSq9qhFhoaAw7owB8MClARIwAeID2pOYYYRqF7UlCNa81KBLXBDeokQB9rXXlVMBobQ6EzxIHZcEQB0MJK%20wLjG4ScAAD8rpKhbmTOGxI1yux3IgA8p5cdoC1judWfATE9Dpp3EgOoDrXWhDetKwNbQQ2aBdYGuAWRG25TaIMIYbbCqdtpW8NYbaehqhuuJU1qI-Q4j9OpRI86NILoXQGE2c7l1Ls3epVds7F2LrIlundFU90boPdutdJ6t2JAUtiRR6pXxTCYMwAw8Q%20DrNMLqSM0lTXstNYJYQPhEiTNCdMGZWQgA)

### cложность в фокусировке

#### html

- tabindex - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

#### js

- focus - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/focus

но если мы используем `document.body.addEventListener` какой тогда смысл в `onKeyDown` на каком-то одном компонентике, если можно "слушать" `body` ...

js вариант **фокусировки** закомментирован, реализован в блоке `- ,- focus`

### тут запустить можно

необходимо кликнуть по контейнеру

```js
const Cell = ({ children, ...props }) => (React.createElement("span", Object.assign({}, props), children));
const Row = ({ children, ...props }) => (React.createElement("div", Object.assign({}, props), children));
// -,-
var KEYS;
(function (KEYS) {
    KEYS["ArrowUp"] = "ArrowUp";
    KEYS["ArrowDown"] = "ArrowDown";
    KEYS["ArrowLeft"] = "ArrowLeft";
    KEYS["ArrowRight"] = "ArrowRight";
    KEYS["Enter"] = "Enter";
})(KEYS || (KEYS = {}));
// -,-
const Matrix = ({ matrix }) => {
    const cellStyle = {
        display: 'inline-block', textAlign: 'center'
    };
    cellStyle.lineHeight = cellStyle.width = cellStyle.height = '30px';
    // -,-
    const [key, setKey] = React.useState('key');
    const [xy, setXY] = React.useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
    let { x, y } = xy;
    const reset = () => { ({ x, y } = xy); };
    const xMax = matrix[0].length - 1;
    const yMax = matrix.length - 1;
    // -,-
    const handleKeyPress = (event) => {
        const { key } = event;
        // -,-
        setKey(key);
        // -,-
        const d = {
            [KEYS.ArrowUp]: () => --y,
            [KEYS.ArrowDown]: () => ++y,
            [KEYS.ArrowLeft]: () => --x,
            [KEYS.ArrowRight]: () => ++x,
            [KEYS.Enter]: () => { },
        };
        // -,-
        const isTrue = q => true === q;
        const isOne = (x, y) => 1 === matrix[y][x];
        const ch = {
            [KEYS.ArrowUp]: () => [y > 0,].every(isTrue),
            [KEYS.ArrowDown]: () => [y < yMax,].every(isTrue),
            [KEYS.ArrowLeft]: () => [x > 0,].every(isTrue),
            [KEYS.ArrowRight]: () => [x < xMax,].every(isTrue),
            [KEYS.Enter]: () => [true].every(isTrue),
        };
        // -,-
        const isOK = key in ch && key in d;
        if (!isOK) {
            console.warn('key in ch', key in ch);
            console.warn('key in d', key in d);
            return;
        }
        while (ch[key]()) {
            d[key]();
            if (isOne(x, y)) {
                setXY({ x, y });
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isOne(x, y))
            reset();
        // -,-
    };
    // -,-
    // - ,- focus
    let div = null;
    // div = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>()
    // let [f, setF] = React.useState(false)
    // React.useEffect(() => {
    //     const list = ['click', 'load'];
    //     const focus = () => {
    //         if (div.current) {
    //             div.current.focus()
    //         }
    //     }
    //     list.forEach(str => document.body.addEventListener(str, focus))
    //     if (!f) {
    //         console.log({ xMax, yMax })
    //         setF(true)
    //     }
    //     return () => {
    //         list.forEach(str => document.body.removeEventListener(str, focus))
    //     }
    // })
    // -, - focus
    const qq = {
        backgroundColor: 'antiquewhite',
        marginLeft: 'auto',
        marginRight: 'auto',
        width: '150px',
    };
    // -,-
    return (React.createElement("div", { tabIndex: 0, onKeyDown: handleKeyPress, style: qq, ref: div },
        React.createElement("p", null, key),
        React.createElement("p", null,
            x,
            " ",
            y),
        matrix.map((arr, i) => React.createElement(Row, null, arr.map((q, j) => React.createElement(Cell, { style: (j === x && i === y) ? { ...cellStyle, backgroundColor: 'gray' } : cellStyle }, q))))));
};
// -,-
const matrix = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
];
// -,-
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Matrix, { matrix: matrix }), document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@^16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@^16.7.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script>
console.log("useState" in React)
console.log("render" in ReactDOM)
</script>
```

### upd: и всё же я бы так написал

```
class KeyboardKeyProvider extends React.Component<KeyboardKeyProvider.$props, KeyboardKeyProvider.$state> {
    state = { key: '' } as KeyboardKeyProvider.$state;
    hK = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
        const { key } = e;
        // console.log({ key })
        if (key in KEYS)
            this.setState({ key });
    };
    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('keydown', this.hK);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('keydown', this.hK);
    }
    render() {
        const Co = this.props.children;
        const { key: keyboardKey } = this.state;
        return (<div>
            {Co({ keyboardKey })}
        </div>);
    }
}
namespace KeyboardKeyProvider {
    interface childrenProps {
        keyboardKey: KEYS;
    }
    export interface $props extends React.ComponentProps<'div'> {
        children: React.FC<React.ComponentProps<'div'> & childrenProps>;
    }
    export interface $state {
        key: any;
    }
}
```

```js
const Cell = ({ children, ...props }) => (React.createElement("span", Object.assign({}, props), children));
var KEYS;
(function (KEYS) {
    KEYS["ArrowUp"] = "ArrowUp";
    KEYS["ArrowDown"] = "ArrowDown";
    KEYS["ArrowLeft"] = "ArrowLeft";
    KEYS["ArrowRight"] = "ArrowRight";
    KEYS["Enter"] = "Enter";
})(KEYS || (KEYS = {}));
class KeyboardKeyProvider extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
        this.state = { key: '' };
        this.hK = (e) => {
            const { key } = e;
            // console.log({ key })
            if (key in KEYS)
                this.setState({ key });
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('keydown', this.hK);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('keydown', this.hK);
    }
    render() {
        const Co = this.props.children;
        const { key: keyboardKey } = this.state;
        return (React.createElement("div", null, Co({ keyboardKey })));
    }
}
const cellStyle = {
    display: 'inline-block', textAlign: 'center'
};
cellStyle.lineHeight = cellStyle.width = cellStyle.height = '30px';
const conteinerStyle = {
    backgroundColor: 'antiquewhite',
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginRight: 'auto',
    width: '150px',
};
class Matrix extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
        this.state = new Matrix.State(this.props.matrix, this.props.keyboardKey);
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // OLD style // По этому названию он будет доступен до 17 версии
    // https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillupdate
    // componentWillUpdate(nP: Readonly<Matrix.$props>, S) {
    //     const { keyboardKey } = nP
    //     this.qqp(keyboardKey)
    // }
    render() {
        const { keyboardKey } = this.state;
        const { x, y } = this.state.xy;
        return (React.createElement("div", { style: conteinerStyle },
            React.createElement("p", null, keyboardKey || '_'),
            React.createElement("p", null,
                x,
                " ",
                y),
            matrix.map((arr, i) => React.createElement(Row, { key: `row-${i}` }, arr.map((q, j) => React.createElement(Cell, { key: `cell-${j}`, style: (j === x && i === y) ? { ...cellStyle, backgroundColor: 'gray' } : cellStyle }, q))))));
    }
}
Matrix.qqp = (nextProps, prevState) => {
    const { keyboardKey } = nextProps;
    if (!keyboardKey)
        return;
    // -,-
    let { xy, max } = prevState;
    let { x, y } = xy;
    const resetXY = () => { ({ x, y } = xy); };
    const setXY = ({ x, y }) => { xy = { x, y }; };
    // -,-
    const d = {
        [KEYS.ArrowUp]: () => --y,
        [KEYS.ArrowDown]: () => ++y,
        [KEYS.ArrowLeft]: () => --x,
        [KEYS.ArrowRight]: () => ++x,
        [KEYS.Enter]: () => { },
    };
    // -,-
    const isTrue = q => true === q;
    const isOne = (x, y) => 1 === matrix[y][x];
    const ch = {
        [KEYS.ArrowUp]: () => [y > 0,].every(isTrue),
        [KEYS.ArrowDown]: () => [y < max.y,].every(isTrue),
        [KEYS.ArrowLeft]: () => [x > 0,].every(isTrue),
        [KEYS.ArrowRight]: () => [x < max.x,].every(isTrue),
        [KEYS.Enter]: () => [true].every(isTrue),
    };
    // -,-
    const isOK = keyboardKey in ch && keyboardKey in d;
    if (!isOK) {
        console.warn('key in ch', keyboardKey in ch);
        console.warn('key in d', keyboardKey in d);
        return;
    }
    while (ch[keyboardKey]()) {
        d[keyboardKey]();
        if (isOne(x, y)) {
            setXY({ x, y });
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!isOne(x, y)) {
        resetXY();
    }
    // -,-
    return { xy, keyboardKey };
};
Matrix.getDerivedStateFromProps = (nextProps, prevState) => {
    // Re-run the filter whenever the list array or filter text change.
    // Note we need to store prevPropsList and prevFilterText to detect changes.
    return Matrix.qqp(nextProps, prevState);
    // --,--
    // return null;
};
(function (Matrix) {
    class State {
        constructor(matrix, keyboardKey) {
            this.matrix = matrix;
            this.keyboardKey = keyboardKey;
            this.xy = { x: 0, y: 0 };
            this.max = {
                x: this.matrix[0].length - 1,
                y: this.matrix.length - 1,
            };
        }
    }
    Matrix.State = State;
})(Matrix || (Matrix = {}));
const Row = ({ children, ...props }) => (React.createElement("div", Object.assign({}, props), children));
const matrix = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
];
// -,-
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(React.Fragment, null,
    React.createElement(KeyboardKeyProvider, null, ({ keyboardKey }) => React.createElement(Matrix, Object.assign({}, { matrix, keyboardKey })))), document.body);
```

```html
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@^16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@^16.7.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    console.log("useState" in React)
    console.log("render" in ReactDOM)
    </script>
```